# Convexity of |y-X'w|^2 given that inverse of X does not exist

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Can we say anything about the convexity of the $|y-X^Tw|^2$ if we know that inverse of $X$ does not exist?

Hessian is $2XX^T$. Given that X is not invertible, can we conclude that $XX^T$ is indefinite hence $|y-X^Tw|^2$ is non-convex?

y and w are column vectors and X is a matrix. w is a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Hessian is positive semidefinite  (even if not invertible), the function remains convex (but maybe not strictly convex).

A trivial example is
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where
$$
|y - X'w|^2 = (y_1 - w_1)^2 + y_2^2
$$
is a convex function, even if it is constant in the direction
$\{ w_1 = const. \}$.

Comment: ... positive **semidefinite**

Comment: I don't know this term. In my mother tongue, we say definite for this. Thank you.

Comment: but isn't the Hessian already positive definite instead of positive semidefinite due to x'AA'x=(A'x)'(A'x) > 0 ?

Comment: yes, this is what I said.

Comment: no you said it is positive 'semi'-definite and I thought it is positive-definite which is stricter than what you said. but you are correct because one can find a non-zero column vector $w$ which can make $w^TXX^Tw$ equal to 0. e.g $w=[0,1]^T$ for the X you defined above.